# Minimum Latency From header Redirect Php

Tags: php, php-5.6

To reduce latency, Generally all the redirection, I have done so far is done by Nginx rules.

Now I have a scenario, where I need to implement a rule which will forward all request to the different port based on some attribute of the logged-in user.

Example

If I hit URL `mysite.com/urltoHit`(auth is done here)
Now based on logged-in user value say user-age-in-site I need to forward it to abc.newsite.com.

Say
mysite.com is running on 8080 port
abc.mysite.com is running on 9090 port

How can we do this with minimum latency?

The code I know is listed below but will increase latency.

```
if($loggedInUser["user-age-in-site"] >= "2 years"){
    header("Location: http://abc.mysite.com");
    die();
}
```

Comment: One thing that might help would be to include [DNS prefetch headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/dns-prefetch) on `mysite.com`, if that is an option. DNS lookups can sometimes take a lot longer than people expect. Also, make sure you redirect to the final location so that no further redirects happen. For instance, if you redirect to the non-secure but that server redirects to the secure, or you redirect to `/` but that site further redirects to `/home`

Comment: I cannot do an internal forward by some means?

Comment: There's client-side redirection and server-side proxy which are pretty much your only two options.

Comment: Inside  PHP how can I do server-side proxy with the different port?

Comment: If you are on nginx, you can read the [documentation here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/). But this probably isn't what you want to do. If someone is on `a.com`, and you want to get content from `b.com`, you can proxy a request to `b.com` pretty easily, however the resources related to the request, images, fonts, js, etc. might still have their URLs set to `b.com`, so unless you also rewrite the HTML thing might break. Further, any cookies from `b.com` cannot be passed on to the client because the client will only store them under `a.com`

Comment: its subdomain not new site